# Google Earth Engine-function (image) condition

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, image, function

Is there a way to set a condition inside function(image) in GEE? In my case, I am trying to return images with NDVI<0.2 only and use them in qualityMosaic function to generate a composite (with NDVI<0.2 in this case). However, when I run the following code the composite shows pixels with high NDVI values (~0.8). Can anyone detect the problem here. Probably the if inside the function in not implemented correctly.

```
// ee.Geometry.Point() function as demonstrated here. 
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.292, 37.9018]);
    
// Import the Landsat 8 TOA image collection. 
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA');
    
// Get the least cloudy image in 2015. 
var image = ee.Image(   l8.filterBounds(point)
        .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31') );
    
var addNDVI = function(image) {   var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');  
 if (ndvi.lt(0.2))
{   return image.addBands(ndvi);   } 
};
    
var withNDVI = l8.map(addNDVI);
    
// Make a "low ndvi" pixel composite. 
var low_ndvi = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');
    
// Display the result. 
var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}; 
Map.addLayer(low_ndvi, visParams, 'ndvi<0.2 composite');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your script produces a huge image very demanding of time for being displayed. So, I modified your script for only to use tiles touched by your point geometry (supposing it into your ROI).

On the other hand, this condition, `ndvi.lt(0.2)`, produces images with zeroes and ones and it is necessary to multiply each ndvi image by itself for obtaining images with its respective ndvi values (you don't need the 'if' statement). For a better visualization, it is also convenient masking zero values.

Instead of 'qualityMosaic('NDVI')', I used 'first' method for corroborating that the function works as expected. However, it can also be used the 'qualityMosaic' method. I used the 'NDVI' band with a palette of colors (instead of 'B4', 'B3', 'B2' bands).

My script looks as follows:

```
// ee.Geometry.Point() function as demonstrated here. 
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.292, 37.9018]);
    
// Import the Landsat 8 TOA image collection. 
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(point)
  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31');

// Get the least cloudy image in 2015. 
//var image = ee.Image(   l8.filterBounds(point)
//        .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31') );
    
var NDVI = function(image) {   
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

  var ndvi_lt02 = ndvi.lt(0.2)
  .updateMask(ndvi.lt(0.2));

  return ndvi_lt02.multiply(ndvi);
  
};
    
var withNDVI = l8.map(NDVI);

print(withNDVI);
    
// Make a "low ndvi" pixel composite. 
var low_ndvi = withNDVI.first()
  .select('NDVI');

print(low_ndvi);
    
// Display the result. 
var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["NDVI"],
                     "min":-0.19763781130313873,
                     "max":0.19998399913311005,
                     "palette":["ff710a","efff0a","2cff20","62e9ff","102cff","fc1eff"]};

Map.addLayer(low_ndvi, imageVisParam, 'ndvi<0.2 composite');

//Map.addLayer(point);
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got following result.

[image]

Inside the tile, ndvi values (including masked) were as expected.

By using your visualization parameters, above script has to be modified as follows.

```
// ee.Geometry.Point() function as demonstrated here. 
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.292, 37.9018]);
    
// Import the Landsat 8 TOA image collection. 
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(point)
  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31');

// Get the least cloudy image in 2015. 
//var image = ee.Image(   l8.filterBounds(point)
//        .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31') );
    
var NDVI = function(image) {   
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

  var ndvi_lt02 = ndvi.lt(0.2)
  .updateMask(ndvi.lt(0.2));
  
  ndvi_lt02 = ndvi_lt02.multiply(ndvi);

  return image.addBands(ndvi_lt02);
  
};
    
var withNDVI = l8.map(NDVI);

print(withNDVI);
    
// Make a "low ndvi" pixel composite. 
var low_ndvi = withNDVI.first()
  .select('B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'NDVI');

print(low_ndvi);
    
// Display the result. 
var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["NDVI"],
                     "min":-0.19763781130313873,
                     "max":0.19998399913311005,
                     "palette":["ff710a","efff0a","2cff20","62e9ff","102cff","fc1eff"]};

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}; 

Map.addLayer(low_ndvi, visParams, 'ndvi<0.2 composite');

//Map.addLayer(point);
```

After running it in GEE code editor, you only can corroborate that it works as expected watching in Inspector Tab; as it can be observed in following image.

[image]